# Setting the lock screen timeout

Tags: lock-screens, battery-life

On my Nexus 4, when I press the power button to access the lock screen (say, to check the time), the screen doesn't turn itself off for 30 seconds. This seems like an excessive delay. On my previous Froyo phone, the lock screen would time out in about 5 seconds. Is there an option to set the lock screen timeout? The only timeout-related settings I found are "Display -> Sleep" and "Security -> Automatically lock", but these don't seem to control what I want.

I could, of course, press the power button again to turn the screen off, but... laziness.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to a lower timeout (15 seconds)? Would it sleep?

Comment: In that case, it does sleep from the lock screen in 15 seconds, but it also sleeps in 15 seconds when I'm reading a web page or something, so that's not quite what I want.

Comment: Try changing it to 30 seconds now. See if it works. :)

Comment: I don't understand how that's going to make it do what I want?

Comment: By the way, are you using stock ROM, or custom ROM?

Comment: I'm on stock Jelly Bean 4.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

You could watch out for an automation solution. I e.g. use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) for a lot of things like that (yeah, it's EUR 5 -- but you can obtain a free 7-day trial at the project page, and according to the dev even make it work another 7 days by exporting its settings, uninstall, reinstall, import settings). Rawly described: You combine events/conditions with tasks. In your case, you'd e.g. set the default timeout to 30s, and have Tasker take care for specialities:

- Profile "Reading":

  - **Condition:** App running (Browser, eBook-Reader, ... -- make your choices)
  - **Task:** Set screen timeout to 2min (automatically reverts when condition is no longer met)
- Profile "LockScreen":

  - **Condition**: [Screenlock On]
  - **Task:** Timeout 15s

You've got the idea. Unfortunately (as indicated by the square brackets), *Tasker* seems to have no condition for "Screenlock active" (or I did not find it), so this might require some addon (Locale addons are compatible). Nevertheless, you've got the idea -- and there are other automation solutions out there on the Playstore which might do the job to your liking, and even may be cheaper. I'd look out for addons, then check [Llama - Location Profiles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) etc. as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to do just that in tasker,

basically you can simply set the screen timeout to 15secs once the screen turns off (which usually is the trigger to turn the lockscreen on :) )

and there also is an event which is called Display Unlocked (which is lockscreen unlocked)
and with that simply turn the screen timeout back to whatever u choose, i.e. 30 minutes.

Comment: Can you add the actual contexts and tasks/actions as a step by step process?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a simple way to reduce the display timeout while on Lock Screen (in case you just want to wake the device, see what time it is, and then want it to lock itself more quickly than your android sleep timeout setting) :

Condition: SecureSettings - failed login attempts 1 and tick the "invert" box.
Action: Display timeout (put your desired seconds here).

This profile will detect the Lock Screen and *not* look for any failed attempt and will turn off the screen with your desired timeout.

Note that this condition requires [Secure Settings plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) to be installed.